# How to get updates from the server promptly?

Tags: ios

I have an iOS app which displays some information fetched from the server.
The app communicates with the server using REST API, and makes GET requests periodically (or when user pulls-to-refresh). However, we need better synchronization. As soon as data changed on server, we want to reflect it in the mobile app.
How can I get notifications from the server when data changed and update needed? I thought about silent push notifications, but they do not look a right choice here.
Are there alternatives? May socket programming help? I have no an experience in it, but I it is relevant, I will start digging.

Comment: socket or firebase may help. you need to listen to a node on firebase and whenever any update is made on that node, you will be able to catch that in your app's the listener method. So whenever server  have new date, it just change the flag on firebase node which u r listening and your app will know about the flag change. So you can make an API call to server to get new data.

Comment: You could use Silent Notifications to let your devices know that new content is available. So once the server has new data you could send out a notification and the devices responding can then run your GET requests again to retrieve content without showing your user a banner or alert of this notification. I believe it's probably easier than setting up sockets.